# Set value field in a workflow to greater than 45 days

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to create a condition in a SPD workflow "if current item:due date is greater than 45 days".  How do I put the 45 days in the "value" section?

Answer (score 0):

Make the Due Date column calculated =Today+45
and put this condition in SPD
If Current Item:Due Date is Greater than  Variable: Todays Date
or 
create a variable in SPD and assign it to the due date

Comment: The due date is assigned and different for each item in the list.  I can't make it a calculated column.  Is there another way?  I'm trying to set up a workflow so that an email is sent 30 days before an action is due and than again 10 days before an action is due.  I'm trying to prevent the 30 day email from going if the due date is less than 30  days.  For example I created an action with a due date that is in one week.  My workflow sent both the 30 day notification email AND the 10 day notification email.

Comment: In SPD 2013 Find days between Variable: Todays Date and Current Item:Due Date (Output to Variable: noofdays ) If Variable: noofdays is greater than or equal to 0

Comment: I'm in SPD 2010.  I don't see that condition.

Answer (score 0):

In SPD 2013 we have these conditions

Find days between Variable: Todays Date and Current Item:Due Date (Output to Variable: noofdays)

If Variable: noofdays is greater than or equal to 30

and Variable: noofdays is less than or equal to 45

Email Current Item:group name

These are the conditions you can use and acheive the requirement